# Element column length isn't respected when auto mapping a dictionary using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm mapping a dictionary using FluentNHibernate like this:

```
HasMany<MyEntity>(n => n.MyDictionary)
    .AsMap<string>(
        index => index.Column("LCID").Type<int>(),
        element => element.Column("Value").Type<string>().Length(1000)
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

As you can see, I'm specifying a column length for the element column 'Value'.

However, the specified element column length isn't respected; when I look at the exported database schema (I'm generating the database from my mappings) the element column is mapped as `nvarchar(255)`.

The generated HBM seems to be correct:

```
<map table="MyDictionary_Values" name="MyDictionary" mutable="true"
     cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key>
        <column name="MyDictionary_id"/>
    </key>
    <index type="int">
        <column name="LCID"/>
    </index>
    <element type="string" length="1000">
        <column name="Value"/>
    </element>
</map>
```

Here's the incorrect DDL:

```
create table MyDictionary_Values
(
    MyDictionary_Id INT not null,

    Value NVARCHAR(255) null,

    LCID INT not null,
    primary key (MyDictionary_Id, LCID)
)
```

Is this a bug in NHibernate or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It appears that you are telling FNH that the column length is 1000 with this code: `.Length(1000)`  But you say the database is actually configured to have a column length of 255. So all you should need to do is change your code to match the column length in the database. Am I misunderstanding what your problem is?

Comment: I have updated my question to make clear that I am generating my database from the mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this walkthrough :

```
HasMany<MyEntity>(n => n.MyDictionary)
  .AsMap<string>(
      index => index.Column("LCID").Type<int>(),
      element => element.Columns.Clear().Columns.Add("Value", col => col.Length(1000))
  .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```